# Adding properties in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach

I'm sorry for such a simple question with a probably simple answer. I'm trying to add a property to an object in a nested `forEach` loop. For some reason, it's just not working.

I tried using `Object.assign()` creating a new variable then copying the parameter... Just can't get it to work! Here's the code:

```js
req.user.gamesDetails.forEach(game => {
  game.achievements.forEach(achievement => {
    console.log(game.name) // evaluates to game1 (as intended)
    achievement.game = game.name;
    console.log(achievement) // game property doesn't exist!
  })
})
```

```js
const gamesDetails = [{
  "name": "game1",
  "achievements": [{
    "name": "Achievement1",
    "alias": "ach1",
  }]
}]

gamesDetails.forEach(game => {
  game.achievements.forEach(achievement => {
    console.log(game.name) // evaluates to gameName (it's not undefined)
    achievement.game = game.name;
    console.log(achievement) // game property doesn't exist!
  })
})
```

I expected the `achievement.game` to be gameName.

Comment: is achievement an ordinary object?

Comment: what do you get with `console.log(achievement.game )`?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with some sample data for `gamesDetails` array.

Comment: what is your data?

Comment: A gamesDetails object looks like:


`[ { 
 "name" : "game1", 
 "achievements" : 
   [ 
     { 
       "name" : "Achievement1", 
       "alias" : "ach1", 
     } 
   ]
} ]`

I want to add game1 to each one of the achievements.
@AZ_ I get "game1"... As intended. But with console.log(achievement) I don't get it consoled out

Comment: ^ For this `gamesDetails`, the code is working fine. I've added a snippet to the question. It's working as intended

Comment: @adiga for me as well if I use it on the browser's console... but for some reason it doesn't work in my backend (nodejs + express.js)... it always prints the object without the "name" property

Comment: try `Object.defineProperty(achievement, 'game ', {
  value: game.name,
  enumerable: true
});` rather `achievement.game = game.name`

Comment: thanks @AZ_ unfortunately I get the same result... I can print achievement.game and game.name and I get game1 as intended... But if I print achievement I don't get that property

Answer (score 1):

I managed a workaround like this:

```
req.user.gamesDetails.forEach(game => {
    game.achievements.forEach(achievement => {
        const newAchievement = {
            name: achievement.name,
            game: game.name
        }

        achievement = newAchievement;
        console.log(achievement.game) // game1
        console.log(achievement) // game property is now on the object

    })
})
```

It still doesn't explain that odd behaviour but it now works, at least

Answer (score 0):

`req = {
    user: {
        gamesDetails: [{
                name: 'game1',
                achievements: [{
                    id: 1
                }, {
                    id: 2
                }, {
                    id: 3
                }]
            },
            {
                name: 'game2',
                achievements: [{
                    id: 1
                }, {
                    id: 2
                }, {
                    id: 3
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}`

For this structure(based on your code), your code work fine...

Comment: Please don't answer questions which don't include a [mcve]. If sufficient code is not provided, it should be closed until OP provides furthere information

Answer (score -1):

```
Above is updating the value but not updated on value at index.

let arr = req.user.gamesDetails.forEach(game => {
  return game.achievements.forEach((achievement,index) => {
    console.log(game.name) // evaluates to gameName (it's not undefined)
game.achievements[index].achievement.game = game.name;
    console.log(achievement) // game property doesn't exist!
    return achievement
  })
})
```

Comment: The first parameter `achievement` is same as `game.achievements[index]`

Comment: I tried this approach also... Also didn't work. Strange!